# Prerequisites in assorted directories

Tags: makefile, rule, gnu-make

I have a variable with a list of prerequisites in varying directories, each specified by a relative path. For example:

```
HTML_FILES := ../foo1/bar1.html ../foo1/bar2.html ../foo2/bar3.html foo3/bar4.html
```

(Note that this variable is actually generated, so the full list of folders isn't known in advance.)

For each of these, I want to generate a target file in the current directory, e.g. `bar1.xml, bar2.xml, bar3.xml, bar4.xml`.

How can I write a rule which will match for this? This is as close as I've come. It seems like something magic in the place of ?????? might do the trick.

```
build: $(XML_FILES)
$(XML_FILES): %.xml : ??????/%.html
        perl $(HTML_TO_XML) $<
```

Comment: `HTML_FILES` is a variable, isn't it? If it is, then it seems that you've missed an equal sign: `HTML_FILES := ...`

Comment: However, I've already answered you in assumption it is a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`vpath`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search).

```
vpath %.html $(dir $(HTML_FILES))
```

Now one can use simple pattern rule as follows:

```
$(XML_FILES): %.xml : %.html
    perl $(HTML_TO_XML) $<
```

This should be enough to get things work, but I'm not sure how it would behave if there are some files with the same name in different directories, like `../foo1/bar.html` and `../foo2/bar.html`.

Comment: +1, and I think your caveat is overcautious: in that case you couldn't make two local versions of `bar.xml`, so the task would be impossible anyway.

Comment: @Beta, hmmm, yes, indeed. :-)

Comment: Thanks! And in my case, I can assume that we won't have filename clashes, so this works fine.